# Connecting program to module in SystemVerilog

Tags: parameters, module, verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to connect between a top level module and a program block in SystemVeilog using interface.

I succeed in passing the wires, but I couldn't do it also for the parameters.

How can I pass the **parameters** in the module to the program?
Is it possible in any way?

Answer (score 2):

You pass a `parameter` to a `program` in the same way as you pass one to a `module`.  Refer to the IEEE Std 1800-2012, Section "24. Programs".  For example:

```
module tb;
    test #(.WIDTH(8)) test ();
endmodule

program test;
    parameter WIDTH = 5;
    initial $display("WIDTH = %0d", WIDTH);
endprogram
```

Output:

```
WIDTH = 8
```